# Setting xmlhttpRequest.setRequestHeader for an ajax call?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

When I have an ajax call why should i set xmlhttpRequest.setRequestHeader ? is it not obvious from the ajax object that we are sending an ajax request.

Comment: What request header are you talking about? There is unlimited possibilities.

Comment: I mean to say if i want to identify on php that the request is an ajax request then is it mandatory to  set xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded') in js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand first that AJAX request are HTTP request. When you add

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','XXXXXXXXX');
```

it adds an header that define what kind of data will be contained in the body of the request. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` means that the data will be form data. The data format could be something else. It's just that form data is the most common thing you will send to a server.

Comment: So if i use a drop down or a select box.I will still have to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: @Aditya You only need to use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when you want to send POST data with your request.

Comment: @HolyVier Got it Thanks, also is it mandatory to setRequestHeader?

Comment: @Aditya It's only needed when you want to add header that aren't there by default. In most case, you don't need to add any, so it's not mandatory at all.

Comment: @HoLyVier ,  have read that $_SERVER is not a variable generated by php it is generated by the webserver.Do you mean that by setting setReQuestHeader , we are adding key to $_Server?

Comment: @Aditya $_SERVER are variable related to the server and the environment in which your script runs, it's not related to the query. If you want to retrieve the headers that where sent, you can use the function get_headers(http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php).

Comment: @Holyvier If i set xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH','XMLHttpRequest')   then can i retrive it like $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']

Comment: @Aditya HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header is a special case, normally you have to retrieve them through the get_headers function.

Comment: Just a correction for those who are reading the comments, I made a mistake in the function name to get the requested header from the browser, it's apache_request_headers, not get_headers.

Comment: @Holvier Thanks with your help , I have solved the issue and learned in the process.